# What exactly is Luneshine?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I've seen a gun in my inventory with a Luneshine effect. IIRC, the effect wasn't a normal stat that can come on a gun. Is this something that you have to unlock? What exactly does the Luneshine keyword do?
Thanks!

Note: I'm not asking about the effect after the keyword, I'm asking about the actual Luneshine keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luneshine is not something that needs to be unlocked. You can pickup items with Luneshine.

> Luneshine - Luneshine is an additional feature that an item may
>   possess, and can be found on items found throughout the game.

[Source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Borderlands:_The_Pre-Sequel)

The keyword defined on the wiki just says that Luneshine is an additional feature that an item may possess. I'm assuming the word itself is just a play on the word "Moonshine".

Additionally:

You can get Luneshine on items that you collect from the Grinder. You have a greater chance at success if you use Moonstones when using the Grinder.

Comment: You can *only* get luneshine by spending moonstones, as I understand it. They can also come from moonstone chests.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually kinda disappointing. I was hoping for a little more depth than just another stat with a word in front of it.